# Identifier of Neo4j database instance

Tags: neo4j

I have several Neo4j databases which I'm using with one Neo4j server. I'm switching these databases (stop server, copy database to required database path, start server).

Is there any way how to identify which database is currently used? Is there any unique ID in neo4j database which I can use? Because I don't see any identifier in Neo4j API.

Yes, I can create node with label "DatabaseId" and store some unique identifier in this node, but I can't add additional data into existing Neo4j database (my application is not permitted to do any changes in Neo4j database).

Yes, I can analyze data in Neo4j database and create some UUID from these data but data in database can be changed by other application from time to time.

Or is there any "system node" in Neo4j database which I can create and this node is not visible for Cypher? Because this type of change of data is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Neo4j database maintains a internal storeId. You can access it either via neo4j-shell with the following command:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ dbinfo -g Kernel StoreId
{"StoreId": "550503bbc2af134e"}
```

Other option is to use JMX which exposes the same information.